# How to borrow a value stored in HashMap to a function in tokio app

Tags: rust, borrow-checker, rust-tokio

I am just a beginner in Rust and so far I have managed to obey borrow-checker's warnings in a async-heavy tokio app until now.

Basically I have a struct which has a HashMap of games. I want to insert a created game into the hashmap and at the same time pass it to a game_loop that I spawn with `tokio::spawn`. Game loop will update the game but I also want to be able to retrieve the game from the hashmap to execute some functions to check its state etc.

I've tried wrapping it in Arc and Mutexes and whatnot. At the moment I just clone it to the game_loop but - as smarter people probably know - that will only pass a clone of the original and the entity in the hashmap wont update.

GameManager

```
pub struct GameManager {
    games: HashMap<Uuid, Game>,
}
impl GameManager {
    fn find_or_create_game(&mut self, user_options: &GameOptions) -> Uuid {
        for g in self.games.values() {
            println!("game id {:?}", g.id);
            println!("game players {:?}", g.state.get_players());
            if g.allows_joining() && g.matches_player_options(user_options) {
                println!("Joining existing game");
                return g.id;
            }
        }
        let rng = ::rand::rngs::StdRng::from_seed(OsRng.gen());
        let mut game = Game::new(Some(user_options.clone()), rng);
        let game_id = game.id;
        let (game_sender, game_receiver) = mpsc::unbounded_channel::<GameEvent>();
        let broadcast = self.broadcast.clone();
        self.game_channels.insert(game_id, game_sender.clone());
        self.games.insert(game_id, game);
        tokio::spawn(game_loop(game, broadcast, game_receiver));
        return game_id;
    }
}
```

game_loop

```
pub async fn game_loop(
    mut game: Game,
    broadcast: UnboundedSender<ServerEvent>,
    mut receiver: UnboundedReceiver<GameEvent>,
) -> Result<(), io::Error> {
    let dur = std::time::Duration::from_secs_f64(1.0 / game.state.options.fps as f64);
    let mut interval = tokio::time::interval(dur);
    loop {
        interval.tick().await;
        while let Some(is_event) = unconstrained(receiver.recv()).now_or_never() {
            if let Some(event) = is_event {
                handle_game_event(event, &mut game, &broadcast);
            }
        }
        if game.has_ended() {
            break;
        } else {
            game.tick();
            let _ = broadcast.send(ServerEvent::Tick(game.get_tick()));
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Could you provide an error message?

Comment: 68 |         tokio::spawn(game_loop(game, broadcast, game_receiver));
   |                                ^^^^ value used here after move

Comment: This look like a use case for an Arc, why didn't you succeed using it ?

Comment: Well I might have done something wrong but as I wrapped the game in Arc, in the game_loop line `if game.has_ended() {` then failed due to the game being moved inside handle_game_event in the while loop

Comment: Well, figured it out but thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

Okay yeah, I am a dummy. Thanks @Peterrabbit though for giving me the motivation to try using Arc again. Had to wrap it in a mutex but all together, I am just happy that it now works.

So now it is:

```
pub struct GameManager {
    games: HashMap<Uuid, Arc<Mutex<Game>>>,
}
impl GameManager {
    fn find_or_create_game(&mut self, user_options: &GameOptions) -> Uuid {
        for g in self.games.values() {
            if g.allows_joining() && g.matches_player_options(user_options) {
                println!("Joining existing game");
                return g.id;
            }
        }
        let rng = ::rand::rngs::StdRng::from_seed(OsRng.gen());
        let mut game = Arc::new(Mutex::new(Game::new(Some(user_options.clone()), rng)));
        let game_id = game.lock().await.id;
        let (game_sender, game_receiver) = mpsc::unbounded_channel::<GameEvent>();
        let broadcast = self.broadcast.clone();
        self.game_channels.insert(game_id, game_sender.clone());
        self.games.insert(game_id, game.clone());
        tokio::spawn(game_loop(game.clone(), broadcast, game_receiver));
        return game_id;
    }
}
```

```
pub async fn game_loop(
    mut game: Arc<Mutex<Game>>,
    broadcast: UnboundedSender<ServerEvent>,
    mut receiver: UnboundedReceiver<GameEvent>,
) -> Result<(), io::Error> {
    let dur = std::time::Duration::from_secs_f64(1.0 / game.lock().await.state.options.fps as f64);
    let mut interval = tokio::time::interval(dur);
    loop {
        interval.tick().await;
        while let Some(is_event) = unconstrained(receiver.recv()).now_or_never() {
            if let Some(event) = is_event {
                handle_game_event(event, &mut game, &broadcast).await;
            }
        }
        if game.lock().await.has_ended() {
            break;
        } else if game.lock().await.is_running() {
            handle_game_event(GameEvent::Tick(), &mut game, &broadcast).await;
        }
    }
    Ok(())
}
```